# Existence of a solution to the Dirichlet problem

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be a regular domain (a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary). Let $g\in H^{\frac12}(\Omega)$ and let
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{d\!}
H^1_g(\Omega):=\{u\in H^1(\Omega):\text{Tr}(u)=g\}$$
where $\text{Tr}$ is the trace operator.
The **Dirichlet Problem** consists in finding which $u\in H^1_g(\Omega)$ minimize the following integral
$$
F(u):=\int_{\Omega} \left[\frac{|\nabla u|^2}{2}-fu\right]\Dm x$$
where $f$ is a fixed $L^2(\Omega)$ function. I already know that if a solution exists then it's unique, but I'm having some difficulties in the existence proof.

**My attempt of understanding the proof**

Let $\{u_n\}\subseteq H^1_g(\Omega)$ be a minimizing sequence, i.e. a sequence such that

$$F(u_n)\to \inf_{u\in H^1_g(\Omega)} F$$

We just have to prove that $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $H^1(\Omega)$ (because then it admits a weakly convergent subsequence and I understand well that its limit is a solution). Let $G$ be a $H^1(\Omega)$ function such that $g=\text{Tr}(G)$. I can define $v_n:=u_n-G\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and now I just need to prove $\{v_n\}$ is bounded in $H^1(\Omega)$.

The proof proceeds using the following inequalities
$$
\begin{split}
\|v_n\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 &\leq C \|v_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
& \leq C (\|\nabla u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\|\nabla G\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2) \\
& \leq C_1(1+\|u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}) \leq C_2(1+\|v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)})\leq C_2(1+\|v_n\|_{H^1(\Omega)})
\end{split}
$$
I understand just few of these 5 inequalities. I'll comment them in order

1. Clearly
   $$
   \|v_n\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2=(\|v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|\nabla v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)})^2\leq (K\|\nabla v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|\nabla v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)})^2$$
   where I simply used [Poincarè inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) in the last step.
2. Triangular inequality.
3. I don't know. I think my notes suggest that we should somehow use the fact that
   $$
   \frac{1}{2}\|\nabla u_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}-\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq F(u_n)\leq F(G)+1.
   $$
   I perfectly understand these inequalities but I don't know how to use them.
4. I think that we are simply using $\|u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|G\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ so if $C_2=C_1+\|G\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ everything holds but I'm not really sure. Am I right?
5. Obviously $\|v_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|v_n\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$.

Thank you in advance. I'm trying to reconstruct the proof of the course so I'm NOT primarily interested in alternative approaches.

Comment: There might be an error, I don't think $||u_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}$, $||v_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}$, or $||v_n||_{H^1(\Omega)}$ should be squared after the third $\leq$. After all, $||v_n||_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 \leq C_2(1+||v_n||_{H^1(\Omega)}^2)$ is trivial, and you had exactly the right idea for 3., though you don't really need $F(G)$, since $F(u_n)$ is already bounded.

Comment: @WillowWisp You are right: there was a typo. But how do I use that idea for 3? It's not clear to me. And is my idea for 4 correct?

Comment: Since $F(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence, you can write $\frac{||\nabla u_n||^2_{L^2(\Omega)}}{2}-||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}||u_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq F(u_n)\leq C'$, and so $\frac{||\nabla u_n||^2_{L^2(\Omega)}}{2} \leq 2C' + 2||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}||u_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}$. Defining for example $C_1 = C\max(||\nabla G||_{L^2(\Omega)} + 2C'\, , \, 2||f||_{L^2(\Omega)})$, we get the third inequality. And yes, what you did for 4. is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)